# Access VBA: use Boolean variable to lock/unlock form controls

Tags: ms-access, vba, boolean, case

I set up the following public function to help me lock and enable(false) or vise versa, specific controls on a form.  This way I can lock/enable them all, or I can unlock and enable the A group or B group, depending on a combo box chosen.  I set this up, and it seems the locked is working, but not the NOT enabled.

I am passing which group of controls to flip, and then a boolean to lock them as true or false.  The enabled properties of  those controls should be the inverse of the boolean variable or NOT of the variable.

Can someone please see what I may need to adjust?

```
Public Function CostModelLock(LockType As String, LockOn As Boolean)
    Select Case LockType
        Case "A"
            'Lock A controls
            Forms!frmRequest.AField1.Locked = LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.AField2.Locked = LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.AField3.Locked = LockOn

            'Enable A controls
            Forms!frmRequest.AField1.Enabled = Not LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.AField2.Enabled = Not LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.AField3.Enabled = Not LockOn

        Case "B"

            'Lock B controls
            Forms!frmRequest.BField1.Locked = LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.BField2.Locked = LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.BField3.Locked = LockOn

            'Enable B controls
            Forms!frmRequest.BField1.Enabled = Not LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.BField2.Enabled = Not LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.BField3.Enabled = Not LockOn

    End Select
    Forms!frmRequest.Repaint
End Function
```

---

Edit - Continue:

Yes, I am trying to lock it and disabling grays it out.  I could just flip visibility, but I was trying to avoid that, so the user could fill out both, if it applied, but only have 1 set active at a time.  I want the ones that are not the option they chose, to be grayed out, so it is clear that those fields are not in play.  I have a combo box, which is how the user chooses which set they need and this function runs in the after update of that combo.

On load of the form I have this function run on both sets, to make sure they are locked.  That is because the form loads with no records.  They have to use a combo to find a request, or click new to start a new one.  In the after update, I have the following code:

```
If Nz(Me.FKCostModelType.Value) <> 0 Then
    If Me.FKCostModelType.Column(0) = 1 Then
        Call CostModelLock("A", False)
        Call CostModelLock("B", True)
    ElseIf Me.FKCostModelType.Column(0) = 2 Then
        Call CostModelLock("B", False)
        Call CostModelLock("A", True)
    End If
ElseIf Nz(Me.FKCostModelType.Value) = 0 Then
    Call CostModelLock("A", True)
    Call CostModelLock("B", True)
End If
```

I tried switching the function order around to disable and then lock, but that didn't work either. I will also add the above code to the find request, so that once a request is found, that section is set properly.  I have updated the originally posted code above, to add a variable that is set by an if statement to set the inverse of the boolean that is passed to the function, so I can more easily pass the opposite boolean to the control.

```
Public Function CostModelLock(LockType As String, LockOn As Boolean)
    Dim NotLockOn As Boolean

    If LockOn = True Then
        NotLockOn = False
    Else
        NotLockOn = True
    End If

    Select Case LockType
        Case "A"
            'Enable A controls
            Forms!frmRequest.AField1.Enabled = NotLockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.AField2.Enabled = NotLockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.AField3.Enabled = NotLockOn

            'Lock A controls
            Forms!frmRequest.AField1.Locked = LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.AField2.Locked = LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.AField3.Locked = LockOn

        Case "B"
            'Enable B controls
            Forms!frmRequest.BField1.Enabled = NotLockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.BField2.Enabled = NotLockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.BField3.Enabled = NotLockOn

            'Lock B controls
            Forms!frmRequest.BField1.Locked = LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.BField2.Locked = LockOn
            Forms!frmRequest.BField3.Locked = LockOn

    End Select
    Forms!frmRequest.Repaint
End Function
```

It's not a huge deal.  I may just remove the enabled property settings and see if I can just gray them out, like the enabled property does.

Thank you all for the responses!  It helps a lot to get advice from developers who are really good at all of this.

---

Continued Again:

ok, so I have rewritten it again, but its still not working how I want and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  below is the public function, and then the after update of the combo, where a user chooses the model they want, and this function fires off to set the 2 groups of controls appropriately.

Public Function Code:

```
Public Function CostModelLock(TagType As String, LockOn As Boolean)
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim bColor As String

    Set frm = Forms!frmRequest
    If LockOn = True Then
        bColor = RGB(192, 192, 192)
    Else
        bColor = vbWhite
    End If

    'Loop through every control on the form
    For Each ctl In frm.Controls
    'Look for a Particular Tag
        If ctl.Tag = TagType And (TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox) Then
            ctl.Locked = LockOn
            ctl.BackColor = bColor
        End If
    Next ctl
    frm.Repaint
End Function
```

After Update of combo to fire public function:

```
Private Sub FKCostModelType_AfterUpdate()
    If Nz(Me.FKCostModelType.Value) <> 0 Then
        If Me.FKCostModelType.Column(0) = 1 Then
            Call CostModelLock("ReqA", False)
            Call CostModelLock("ReqB", True)
        ElseIf Me.FKCostModelType.Column(0) = 2 Then
            Call CostModelLock("ReqB", False)
            Call CostModelLock("ReqA", True)
        End If
    ElseIf Nz(Me.FKCostModelType.Value) = 0 Then
        Call CostModelLock("ReqA", True)
        Call CostModelLock("ReqB", True)
    End If
    Call UpdateCostEstimate
End Sub
```

I also have code in a combo to find a record.  That is this:

```
Private Sub cboFindRequest_AfterUpdate()
    Dim ctl As Control
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tblRequest"
    With Me.RecordsetClone
        .FindFirst "ID = " & _
        Me.cboFindRequest.Column(0)
        If Not .NoMatch Then
            Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
            'Set detail, footer and save button visible
            Me.Detail.Visible = True
            Me.FormFooter.Visible = True
            Me.cmdSave.Visible = True
            'Set new record and cancel not visible
            Me.cmdNew.Visible = False
            Me.cmdCancel.Visible = False
            'setErr formats red borders around controls, and this is set to false, to remove any red borders
            For Each ctl In Forms!frmSoftwareRequest.Controls
                setErr ctl, False
            Next ctl
            'Set focus on first field, so find combo doesn't have focus and can be set to not visible
            Me.RequestName.SetFocus
            Me.cboFindRequest.Visible = False
            Me.Requery
            'call the after update function from above
            FKCostModelType_AfterUpdate
            'call a function to update a calculated control on form
            UpdateCostEstimate
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

2 things are going wrong right now - one is that the controls aren't getting locked properly.  I use the combo to find a request, and then scroll down to the section with the combo to choose a cost model.  When I try to change that combo, the second issue happens.  I get an error : The data has been changed.  Another user edited this record and saved the changes before you attempted to save your changes.  Re-edit the record.

Ugh.  I'm sure I'm doing 10 things wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what.  The first function in this new edit (CostModelLock) I think the issue there is the frm and ctl calls I have been doing a debug.print and such, but not seeing what I would expect to happen.  I can give more info, but not sure what to provide.  Help is really appreciated!

Comment: Try disabling *then* locking and unlocking *then* enabling.

Comment: Please explain what isn't working the way you want.  Also explain how is this function called, and from where.

Comment: Trouble shoot.  Reduce your function to one line: `Forms!frmRequest.BField3.Enabled = False`.  Does that work?  Then expand from there.  We really need to see a bit of the code that CALLS this function.

Comment: Why do you need to both lock and disable? Shouldn't doing just one of these things be sufficient?

Comment: @JohnBingham: If you only disable, the control gets grayed out. If you also lock, the control is displayed normally.

Comment: More notes: If this code runs after `On Error Resume Next`, remove that. -- `.Repaint` isn't necessary.

Comment: @Gustav: Yes that is true, but so what? Just locking it does the same thing. Making it disabled takes it out of the tab order, but if it was previously editable, why would you then want to take it out of tab order?

Comment: @JohnBingham: "Just locking it does the same thing". No, then the control still can get focus. ".. if it was previously editable," Who says it was? It all depends. If you do a lot of development work, you will over time find options for all four settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I am answering my own question, so that I can put my whole code out here, in case it helps someone else.  I will also mark up Gustav's answer, since it led me here.

First, This is the final public function, which disables and locks each control that has the tag property set to the value passed through the TagType, and is a text box or a combo box.

```
Public Function CostModelLock(TagType As String, LockOn As Boolean)
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim bColor As String
    Dim NotLockOn

    If LockOn = True Then
        NotLockOn = False
    Else
        NotLockOn = True
    End If

    If LockOn = True Then
        bColor = RGB(192, 192, 192)
    Else
        bColor = vbWhite
    End If

    'Loop through every control on the form
    For Each ctl In Forms!frmRequest.Controls
    Debug.Print ctl.Name
        If ctl.Tag = TagType Then
        Debug.Print ctl.Tag
            If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
            Debug.Print Nz(ctl.ControlType, 0)
            Debug.Print ctl.Locked
                ctl.Enabled = NotLockOn
                ctl.Locked = LockOn
                ctl.BackColor = bColor
            Debug.Print ctl.Locked
            End If
        Else
        Debug.Print ctl.Tag
        End If

    Next ctl
    Forms!frmSoftwareRequest.Repaint
End Function
```

I have a redundant enable and back color going on, but that won't hurt anything.  I will likely remove the back color part, but not concerned too much right now.

The afterupdate of a combo on the form now calls a public function, so that I can call this other function whereever I need:

```
Public Function ActiveCostModel()
    If Nz(Forms!frmRequest.FKCostModelType.Value) <> 0 Then
        If Forms!frmRequest.FKCostModelType.Column(0) = 1 Then
            CostModelLock "ReqCostA", False
            CostModelLock "ReqCostB", True
        ElseIf Forms!frmRequest.FKCostModelType.Column(0) = 2 Then
            CostModelLock "ReqCostB", False
            CostModelLock "ReqCostA", True
        End If
    ElseIf Nz(Forms!frmRequest.FKCostModelType.Value) = 0 Then
        CostModelLock "ReqCostA", True
        CostModelLock "ReqCostB", True
    End If
    Call UpdateCostEstimate
End Function
```

And the best part --> It all works!  Thank you so much @Gustav and everyone else for all your responses and help!

Comment: Great! And thanks for the feedback. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 2):

**If**, as Hans noted, none of the controls has focus, your code should work, so - most likely - something else is going on.

As a sidenote, your code can be reduced to:

```
Public Function CostModelLock(LockType As String, LockOn As Boolean)

    Dim Index As Integer

    For Index = 1 to 3
        With Forms!frmRequest(LockType & "Field" & CStr(Index))
            .Locked = LockOn
            .Enabled = Not LockOn
        End With
    Next
    Forms!frmRequest.Repaint

End Function
```

Comment: Interesting.  Is that index the tab index?  I just learned about using the tag property of a control.  It allows me to group the sets of controls to 1 tag, so I can loop through just those.  In the end, trying to save or close the form results in a validation function to alert the user if required info isn't filled in.  For this set, They need to choose a model, and fill out all 3 fields of that model. It is creating the need for a lot of code, but I love any opportunity to make it as slick as possible.  I will have to play around with what you posted, to see how that would work. Thanks!

Comment: No, here _Index_ is just a part of the control's _name_. But you are right; you can assign a _Tag_ to the controls to loop and then check the Tag, or the _TabOrder_ can also be used, though it may be more difficult as most controls will have a TabOrder assigned. Also, you can check the _ControlType_ to filter for specific controls ignoring there names or other properties.

Comment: Yeah, I am going to try keeping the locking/unlocking and just try graying out the background, if it is being locked.  I'll post once I test!

Comment: If I want to use the part where you say "With Forms!frmRequest(LockType & "Field" & CStr(Index))  I want to do that, but I'm using the tag instead.  I am not sure of the syntax.  I am not sure what the LockType variable should be either.  I will be looking this up, but if you know, that would be helpful.  This is what I have so far:

Comment: For Each ctr In Forms!frmRequest.Controls
 'Look for a Particular Tag
  If ctr.Tag = TagType Then
  
  End If
 
 Next ctr
the TagType will have the name of the tag group that will be passed to the function, along with the boolean true false for locking or unlocking (and graying out or not)

Comment: Yes, you will have to loop the controls to check the Tag of these. Only using the Name you can assign a control directly.

Comment: I edited my original post to show you what I have right now.  Something is wrong with me for each ctl in frm,controls . It doesn't seem to be locking the ones that should lock and despite my attempts to troubleshoot, I'm not figuring it out.  I started my newest update with Continued Again: